# Program that reads num and prints from 1 to num

Tags: java, math, logic

i need help in logic,  i need the program to read an integer from user and then prints all the integers from 1 to num1. here's what i got :

```
 import java.util.Scanner;

     public class test 
    {       
    public static void main(String []args)
    {    

        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

        int num1;
        int num2;

        System.out.println("Enter any number:");
        num1 = scan.nextInt();

    while (num1<=num2) {    

        System.out.println(num+1);
    }
     }
    }
```

Comment: Your problem has two parts; isolate the one you need help with, and ask about *that*.

Comment: Make use of `num1++`. It means `num1 = num1 + 1`. That may be useful in your loop

Comment: Or maybe even three parts, depending on how you count them. You can start by reading your compile errors as what you have won't even compile.

Comment: This looks like a homework assignment for the loop chapter. Just make clever use of a for loop or while loop. Do this different ways using different loops for best practice. Copying an answer below won't help you learn the concepts.

Answer (score 3):

Try this out:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
    class test {
        public static void main(String[] args) {

            Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

            int number;

            System.out.println("Enter any number:");
             // Note : The below statement will fail if user does not enter integer value
            number = scan.nextInt();

            // You can use while loop as well but for loop provides cleaner approach for iteration
            for (int i = 1; i <= number; i++) {
                // Print numbers sequentially from 1 to number
                System.out.println(i);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Might I suggest you add braces around the body of the `for` loop? They're not necessary but IMHO it would make your code a little more readable with the comment line being there.

Comment: @user3081689: Please accept if you are satisfied with the answer. Here is the link for more details : http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 0):

> Program that reads num and prints from 1 to num

Try,

```
 System.out.println("Enter any number:");
 num1 = scan.nextInt();
 int i=1;
 while (i<=num1) {    
    System.out.println(i);
    i++;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

do like this

```
  int num1=0;
  int num2=0;
  System.out.println("Enter any number:");
  num1 = scan.nextInt();
  while (num2 <= num1) {    
       System.out.println(num2);
       num2++;
  }
```

Comment: hey thanks for the feedbacks, i tried to get this done using while loop . what am i doing wrong here?


  `  import java.util.Scanner;
    
    public class test
    {
     public static void main (String[] args) 
     {
      Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    
            int num;
            int a=1;
    
            System.out.println("Enter any number:");
            num=input.nextInt();
     
     while (a<=num) 
     {
     
            System.out.println(a);
            a++;}
          
     }} `

Comment: @user3081689 replace input.nextInt(); to scan.nextInt();

Comment: yea figured it out! been couple of years since last i coded a java program. thanks alot

Answer (score 0):

thanks alot guys! its been couple of years since last i coded a java program so im a little rusty! here's my final code :

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class test
{
    public static void main (String[] args) 
    {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

        int num;
        int a=1;

        System.out.println("Enter any number:");
        num=scan.nextInt();

    while (a<=num)  
    {

        System.out.println(a);
        a++;}

    }}
```